# Twilio Matching Orginial Message

Tags: c#, sms, twilio

1. Send SMS Message to user - Response gets me a SID (SMf57da38aeceXXXXXXdb393a0f23d2) which i store in database.
2. Clients replys to SMS message - How do I get SID from step 1?

Most other SMS API's I've dealt with send back a reply_to parameter.  I've looked through lots of Twilio docs but I'm struggling to find the answer.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Each individual message is an atomic unit, as this is how text messages are meant to be. However, there are still things you can do to make those messages relate to each other. One way I see a lot of people doing is by relating messages to the phone number, and then ordering them by the date/time stamp.

This will work just fine 9 out of 10 times, and will always guarantee you are following a chain of messages on the correct order.

Let me know if you have a specific situation where such approach wouldn't suffice.

Comment: Thanks - Yeah phone numbers I guess would be one way, I have multiple clients using my system so I would need to purchase a phone number for each client to ensure the messages were routed correctly.  How come other SMS providers have this service but twilio doesn't?

Comment: No, when I say phone number, I really mean using the person's phone number as the identifier. You always get that with each customer's text. Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay.  But my clients (who are independent of each other) might txt the same person (think appointment reminders).  Couldn't guarantee it would be routed back to the original message.

Comment: But that is because text messages are atomic. You can only trace them back to each other if they contain some kind of token in the message body.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Twilio developer evangelist too, hello!

I have another idea that might help you. You can actually [set a cookie](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-do-twilio-cookies-work) to tie messages together over time. There's a [guide on getting started with that in C# here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/tracking-conversations).

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Seems like cookies only last for a short period so I don't think this will suffice.  Am I missing something? Can any US based SMS provider do this? Most other countries I've dealt with have this built in :(